# Find which mysql is running

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5, percona

I have installed mysql 5.5 and percona 5.5 in the same machine. I am not able to identify wheather the running db is mysql or percona. IS there is any way to identify the difference.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT VERSION();` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%';`?

Comment: It shows the version alone.. I want to check percona/mysql. In my case both are 5.5

Comment: Which OS platform are you using? How do you log on to the Database server? You could check which database service is running?

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact results into your question.  Those commands return a lot more than just "5.5".

Answer (score 3):

When you connect to MySQL, just run

```
SELECT SUBSTR(variable_value,1,
LOCATE(' ',variable_value) - 1) DBVersion
FROM information_schema.global_variables
WHERE variable_name='version_comment';
```

You should get this when you connect to MySQL

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTR(variable_value,1,
    -> LOCATE(' ',variable_value) - 1) DBVersion
    -> FROM information_schema.global_variables
    -> WHERE variable_name='version_comment';
+-----------+
| DBVersion |
+-----------+
| MySQL     |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You should get this when you connect to Percona Server

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTR(variable_value,1,
    -> LOCATE(' ',variable_value) - 1) DBVersion
    -> FROM information_schema.global_variables
    -> WHERE variable_name='version_comment';
+-----------+
| DBVersion |
+-----------+
| Percona   |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## CAVEAT

What I suggested works for MySQL 5.1+ and Percona Server 5.1+.

For version 5.0+ of MySQL or Percona Server, you can still get it as follows:

```
SQL="SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version_comment'"
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -p..."
DB=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -Ae"${SQL}" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo ${DB}
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I've modified the above info into this query `SELECT SUBSTR(@@global.version_comment, 1, LOCATE(' ', @@global.version_comment) - 1) AS DBVersion`

Comment: This fails if performance schema is not enabled. See [the following](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125178/112701) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command

```
mysqladmin variables | grep version_comment | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I added the `awk '{print $2}'` to your answer because the second token returned is either `MySQL` or `Percona`. This answer still gets a +1 !!! BTW Welcome to ServerFault.

Answer (score -1):

When you login to mysql it will show you what version of Mysql you are running, if you are running Percona Mysql it will show you Percona Mysql version xyz.

Comment: pls, understand my question. I am not expecting the version. I wants to know the running DB is MySQL or Percona..